# Creating a JSON using a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So say I have some data... say:

```
Dictionary = {'stats': stats, 'lines': arr}
```

Where 'stats' a simple string, and arr is a list of lists:

```
[['A', '#ccebf6', 0, 365, 240, 0], 
['D', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 0], 
['A', '#96dcd8', 0, 65, 230, 1],
 ['T', '#96dcd8', 0, 25, 230, 1], 
['E', '#ccebf6', 0, 370, 240, 2], 
['B', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 3]]
```

and say I use

```
json_string = json.dumps(Dictionary)
```

To get a lovely JSON:

```
'{"stats": {"somestuff..."'"lines": [["some list stuff..]][[..]]"
```

But in arr,  say in last element, I have a an Item I wish to group the "lines" by, call it 'line:' eg

```
[['A', '#ccebf6', 0, 365, 240, 0], 
['D', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 0], 
['A', '#96dcd8', 0, 65, 230, 1],
 ['T', '#96dcd8', 0, 25, 230, 1], 
['E', '#ccebf6', 0, 370, 240, 2], 
['B', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 3]]
```

And I wish to order my lists by that last element, to have them in JSON form:

```
{'lines'[{'val':0, [['A', '#ccebf6', 0, 365, 240, 0], 
               ['D', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 0]],
     'val':1, [['A', '#96dcd8', 0, 65, 230, 1],
              ['T', '#96dcd8', 0, 25, 230, 1]], 
     'val':2, [['E', '#ccebf6', 0, 370, 240, 2]],
     'val'3, [['B', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 3]]}]}
```

Which obviously needs an appropriate dictionary form.

I understand this may not be explained well but let me know if clarification is necessary.

I attempted to sort them using a lambda expression, for that final value in arr. But I do not know how to create them in that format for the dictionary.

Comment: Your desired "dictionary form" is not valid Python. *Updated comment, based on updated question:* your desired "JSON form" is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict to group your items.

```
lines = {}

for row in arr:
    key = row[-1]
    lines.setdefault(key, []).append(row)
```

Result:

```
>>> lines
{0: [['A', '#ccebf6', 0, 365, 240, 0], ['D', '#ccebf6', 0, 25, 250, 0]],
 1: [['A', '#96dcd8', 0, 65,  230, 1], ['T', '#96dcd8', 0, 25, 230, 1]],
 2: [['E', '#ccebf6', 0, 370, 240, 2]],
 3: [['B', '#ccebf6', 0, 25,  250, 3]]}
```